# Sub or Function not defined but there is no error in the coding

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am a compile error: Sub or Function not defined. The code involved is:

```
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

I created a user form, which is exactly the same as I created on another workbook. Everything is identical between both workbooks (data, formatting, coding, user form, everything), but I get this error on one workbook, but not the other. I copied the user form and coding over to this workbook, so nothing was mistyped. Anyone have an idea why one works, but the other doesn't?

I read through the other similar Q&A, but could not find an answer that fit this situation.

I tip my cap to you guru's out there!

Comment: Should be easier to copy the whole file and remove stuff until it stops working :]

Comment: what line is highlighted when it errors out? if it's `Private Sub ClearButton_Click()` then check you have a button on your userform named after `ClearButton`. If it's `Call UserForm_Initialize` then check your userform code pane has a `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` sub code

Comment: @user3598756 - It highlights in yellow the Private Sub line, but also highlights the second line, as well. The button name and the code above match, and the user form has a Private Sub UserForm_Initialize code already.

Comment: step through your code (place a breakpoint at `Call UserForm_Initialize`, run your macro and when it stops at the breakpoint press F8 to step line by line) and see where it actually errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of your button in the new workbook. Button names don't typically copy over when you copy them.

Comment: True, and that is why I set up an identical button on the new file (cut and paste button text and code to minimize any mis-typing them on the new file.)